# New Test Fixture for each iteration over enum members

Tags: googletest

My tests are contained within functions declared with `TEST_F` so that I can use a new test fixture object between tests. For each `TEST_F`, a new instance of the test fixture is created. But what if I wish to loop over an enum in my test and have a new instance of the test fixture for each iteration? What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use [value-parameterized tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests).

You could iterate through the values of an enum like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

enum Malt { bowmore = 10, talisker, scapa };

class Whisky {
 public:
  explicit Whisky(const Malt& malt) : malt_(malt) {}
  bool IsIslay() const { return malt_ == bowmore; }
 private:
  Malt malt_;
};

class DramTest : public testing::TestWithParam<Malt> {
 protected:
  DramTest() : whisky_(GetParam()) {}
  Whisky whisky_;
};

TEST_P(DramTest, IsIslay) {
  if (GetParam() == bowmore)
    EXPECT_TRUE(whisky_.IsIslay());
  else
    EXPECT_FALSE(whisky_.IsIslay());
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(AllMalts, DramTest,
                        testing::Values(bowmore, talisker, scapa));

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

If you have a large number of enum values, you could use the `Range` generator instead of the `Value` one:

```
testing::Range<int>(bowmore, scapa + 1)
```

but this needs some casting in the fixture between ints and the enum type.

Both options suffer from maintenance problems; if you add a new enum value, you need to remember to change the test.

Comment: Also noteworthy: you can iterate over multiple parameters using `tuple<type1, type2>` where `DramTest` uses `Malt` and then using `::testing::Combine()` to string together the sets of parameters.